# Clearing previous search results when making a search

Tags: javascript, html, function

i have been playing around with Punk API, i have made a search tool for any beer that brewdog have made. one issue i cannot seem to fix is that whenever a user makes a second search the results just display below the first search result  and then a third search result would display below that and so on eventually making a huge list of search results. i know need to make a function that clears the search results from the previous search but then bring back the divs for the new search results but i dont know if I'm just over complicating things. any help would be greatly appreciated.

html code :

```
    <div id="beerSearchDiv">
    <h2>Beer Searcher</h2>
    <input id="BeerInputSearch" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search..."></input>
    <button id="BeerSearchBtn">Submit</button>

    <h2 class="search-beer">Search Above For Any Brewdog Beer</h2>
    <div id="search-result" ></div>
    <div class="beer-component" style="display:none;" >
        <div class="beer-title" ></div>
        <div class="beer-tagline" ></div>
        <div class="beer-abv" ></div>
        <div class="beer-image"><img id="imageSearch" alt="beer" /></div>
        <div class="beer-description" ></div>

        <br>
      </div>
</div>


    document.getElementById("BeerSearchBtn").onclick = beerAsk;
randomBeertBtn.addEventListener("click", getData)
```

Javascript code:

```
function beerAsk(e) {

    const resultContainer = document.getElementById("search-result");
    const beerComponent = document.getElementsByClassName("beer-component")[0];
    
    const beerage = document.getElementById("BeerInputSearch").value;
    const url = api + beerage;
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(url)
      .then(reponse => {
        return reponse.json()
  
      })
      .then(data => {
  
        data.forEach((beer) => {
          
          const theBeer = beer.name;
          const theTagline = beer.tagline;
          const theDescription = beer.description;
          const theAbv = beer.abv;
          const thePic = beer.image_url;
  
          
  
          function imgDisplay() {
            if (thePic === null) {
              return document.getElementById('imageSearch').src = "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png";
            } else {
              return thePic;
            }
          }

          let component = beerComponent.cloneNode(true);
  
          let titleBeer = component.getElementsByClassName('beer-title')[0];
          let taglineBeer = component.getElementsByClassName('beer-tagline')[0];
          let abvBeer = component.getElementsByClassName('beer-abv')[0];
          let descriptionBeer = component.getElementsByClassName('beer-description')[0];
          let imgBeer = component.querySelector('.beer-image img'); 
  
          component.style = "display: block;";
          titleBeer.innerHTML += theBeer
          taglineBeer.innerHTML += theTagline
          abvBeer.innerHTML += "ABV: " + theAbv + "%"
          descriptionBeer.innerHTML += theDescription
          imgBeer.src = imgDisplay();
          imgBeer.alt = theBeer;
          
          resultContainer.appendChild(component);
          
        })
  
      })
      
  }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There seems to be nothing in your code that empties the HTML of resultContainer, and the way you modify it is by using `append` which only adds to it.

You can do a custom function, but i think the easiest way would be to just add a line that clears the HTML content of said container after you know you successfully fetched the data (like just before `data.forEach((beer) => {`).

I don't know if this line would work but just as an example something along
`resultContainer.innerHTML = ""` should do fine to reset the list.

If you require more logic you may aswell do a custom function to call here for readability, but i don't think it is required by default.